# R Text mining - how to change texts in R data frame column into several columns with bigram frequencies?

Tags: r, text-mining

In addition to question [R Text mining - how to change texts in R data frame column into several columns with word frequencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258954/r-text-mining-how-to-change-texts-in-r-data-frame-column-into-several-columns) I am wondering how I can manage to make columns with bigrams frequencies instead of just word frequencies.
Again, many thanks in advance!

This is the example data frame (thanks to Tyler Rinker).

```
      person sex adult                                 state code
1         sam   m     0         Computer is fun. Not too fun.   K1
2        greg   m     0               No it's not, it's dumb.   K2
3     teacher   m     1                    What should we do?   K3
4         sam   m     0                  You liar, it stinks!   K4
5        greg   m     0               I am telling the truth!   K5
6       sally   f     0                How can we be certain?   K6
7        greg   m     0                      There is no way.   K7
8         sam   m     0                       I distrust you.   K8
9       sally   f     0           What are you talking about?   K9
10 researcher   f     1         Shall we move on?  Good then.  K10
11       greg   m     0 I'm hungry.  Let's eat.  You already?  K11
```

Data set above:

```
library(qdap); DATA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev version of `qdap` (should go to CRAN within the next few days) does ngrams.  For now you'll need to use the [dev version](https://github.com/trinker/qdap).  On the toy data set this is fast but on a larger data set such as `qdap`'s `mraja1` data set requires ~5 minutes to complete.  You could:

1. Select the bigrams more wisely (i.e., don't use them all as there's going to be a ton)
2. Wait the time
3. [Run it in parallel](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/parallelization-speed-up-functions-in-a-package/)
4. Figure out another way to do this
5. Get a faster computer

Here's the code to get the dev version of `qdap` and run the bigram search:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("qdap", "trinker")
library(qdap)

## this gets the bigrams
bigrams <- sapply(ngrams(DATA$state)[[c("all_n", "n_2")]], paste, collapse=" ")

## This searches by grouping variable for bigram use
termco(DATA$state, DATA$person, bigrams)


## To get raw values
termco(DATA$state, DATA$person, bigrams)[["raw"]]
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler! I think you made my day, again :-). I will try your code as soon as I can.

Comment: It looks very promising! The ngrams functions does the job. However termco gives this error: Error in gsub(paste0(".*?($|'|", paste(paste0("\\", char.keep), collapse = "|"),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 627  Any ideas about what is going wrong?

Comment: No I don't have your data so no idea.  You can try `debug(termco)` and see what's going on.

Comment: I haven't found the cause of the error in the termco yet, but I am very excited about your answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: It turns out to be a matter of just too many texts and words :-)

Comment: So I assume feeding it batches of the text helps.  Can I ask how much text and how many terms caused this error?

Comment: I first tried it with 2400 texts with aproximately an avarage of 180 words each. My solution for now is: i feed the ngrams() a lot less texts first, say 100. After that I can feed termco all the texts, say 2000.

Comment: The only 'problem' I encounter with the termco function is that it doesn't always count bigrams as I expected it would. If there are words used more than once in a text, e.g. twice the word 'the' and twice the word 'and', termco will take these as two different kinds of bigrams: 'the and.1' and 'the and.2' with a freqency of 1 each. I need (and expected) only 'the and' with a frequency of 2. Is there a way to change this termco outcome? Do you see what I mean? Many thanks in advance again :-)

Comment: This is not the appropriate place to ask this.  Please ask the question with a MWE at qdap's [bug reporting](https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues?page=1&state=open)